Laravel deployment to Azure Web App failing if not run from Zip package
I have a vanilla Laravel install and a vanilla Azure Linux Web App and I'm using Github Actions to deploy.
The deployment fails every single time unless WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE is set to 1, in which case Laravel fails because /storage is not writable (the ZIP is mounted as readonly in this deployment method). This deployment method takes about two minutes from committing to the repo to deploying. Unfortunately, it's not usable in a readonly state.
With WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE set to 0, the Build phase passes but Deploy fails. It spends a good few minutes looping on 'Receiving changes' before eventually progressing to a loop of:

##[debug]Deployment status: 1 'Building and Deploying 'b92a9366-2b8d-46f1-93b2-3e5be32794ee'.'. retry after 5 seconds

It's specifically stuck on Incrementally deploying to /home/site/wwwroot.
And seemingly loops endlessly. I eventually have to kill the Github Action after about 2 hours.
I have no idea what else to do or try.

So I've found that downgrading the Azure Web Deploy version from v3 to v2 in the workflow file solved it and it now deploys successfully. This is obviously not a long-term solution and I want to use v3 so if anybody has an idea what's tripping up the newer version, I'm all ears!
